# Create a ranking for user

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I have many users on my DB

```
User -- Points
user1   4
user2   6
user3   2
user4   3
user5   8
user6   9
user7   1
user8   5
```

I'm looking for the easiest and with less errors way to create a 5 rank for specific user. Where the user I choose should be in the middle and have 2 on top and 2 on bottom.

Example 1: user8
I should receive:

```
user5   8
user2   6
**user8 5**
user1   4
user4   3
```

Example2: user4 I should receive:

```
user8   5
user1   4
**user4 3**
user3   2
user7   1
```

Than I have the exceptions. if the user is the TOP1, I need to display the next 4
Example: user 6

```
**user6 9**
user5   8
user2   6
user8   5
user1   4
```

(the same happens if user is the LAST , so in that case i need the next 4 users.

Someone knows a easy way to do that?

EDIT: I'm not asking anyone to do it for me. I'm asking for HINTS. 
I don't understand the down votes. It's just a question.

Comment: what have you tried to do so far? I'd recommend filtering first and then checking if there are two users above the user you want to view.

Comment: what if only 3 users?

Comment: @depperm i thought about that, but in that case i had to think in all possible scenarios . I was wondering if there are some easy way

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza if only 3 users , in that case I show the 3 users for the selected user with the same rules . If only 1 user, I show only that user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>I make it on sql server but work same on postgresql.</del> I include both now.

- check [**Rank()**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/tutorial-window.html) function, and see how handle ties or use `row_number()`
- use a variable instead of `'user3'`

**[Postgres Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/77fcb/3)**
**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://rextester.com/JCUH42932)**

```
WITH playerPoint as (
    SELECT "points"
    FROM Table1
    WHERE "user" = 'user3'
)    
SELECT *
FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM (
                SELECT T."user", 
                       T."points", 
                       CASE WHEN T."points" = P."points"
                            THEN '*****' 
                            ELSE ''
                       END as Selected,
                       RANK() OVER (ORDER BY T."points" DESC) ranking

                FROM       Table1 T
                CROSS JOIN playerPoint P
                WHERE T."points" <= P."points"
                UNION
                SELECT T."user", 
                       T."points",
                       CASE WHEN T."points" = P."points"
                            THEN '*****' 
                            ELSE ''
                       END as Selected,
                       RANK() OVER (ORDER BY T."points" ASC) ranking

                FROM       Table1 T
                CROSS JOIN playerPoint P
                WHERE T."points" >= P."points"

        ) R1
        ORDER BY ranking
        LIMIT 5
     ) R2
ORDER BY POINTS
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

After add `DESC` to last `ORDER BY` with `user8`

[image]

Comment: Hi @Juan. Thanks, but is something wrong there. The user I select should be in the middle on the 5 users the query gives. So in this example you posted, for user8 should be something like this: user5 8
user2 6
user8 5
user1 4
user4 3

Comment: @VaoTsun I put it at begining... Is sql server so I can test it. But sintaxis is the same.

Comment: @62009030 Yes, I didnt include the aditional `ORDER BY`, check my update. I change my sample to `user3`

Comment: @VaoTsun I include the fiddle for Postgres now, you can use it to try your code too.

Comment: I think the postgres fiddle is not correct. The SQL server is correct

Comment: why you think is incorrect? be specific so I can fix it

Comment: The points had the same problem as the first version of SQL server

Comment: I Include a picture of my result with user8. What is wrong?

Comment: yea, was just the DESC

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza would be possible you help me to implement something more to this query?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117141/discussion-between-juan-carlos-oropeza-and-62009030).

Answer (score 0):

here `t5` is your table and `u` is column with users and `r` is column with points... I tried with user value of 'u4' - try with yours...

```
select u,r from (
select *, case when l2 = 'u4' or r1 > 0 or r < max(ur) over () then 1 else 0 end r2 from (
select *, case when l1 = 'u4' or r0 > 0 then 2 else 0 end r1, lag(l1) over (order by r) l2 from (
select *
    --, row_number() over (order by r)
    , lag(u) over (order by r) l1
    , case when u = 'u4' then r else 0 end ur
    --, count(*) over () 
    , case when u = 'u4' then 3 else 0 end r0
from t5 
order by r desc 
) prim
order by r desc 
) sec
) ter
where r2 > 0
order by r desc 
limit 5
```